# how to avoid too many renders per setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, performance, render, setstate

I understand React Native re-renders component in which setState is called.
In example as I tested, there are 7 re-renders per 7 setStates in useEffect codes:

```
  const pullData = async (numToPull, filterPull, sorterPull) => {
    setToSpin(true);
    const response = await AxiosPost(
      sc.Slink.getMailInbox,
      {
        page: 1,
        pageSize: numToPull,
        filterOption: [
          ...filterPull,
          {
            key: "isUnread",
            value: true,
          },
        ],
        sortOption: sorterPull,
      },
      { Authorization: ctxt.authInfo.tokenSF },
      { studio: ctxt.roomInfo.currentLoginRoom }
    );

    setToSpin(false);

    if (response.data.suc) {
      setShowList(response.data.data.items);
      setNumOfDataPulled(response.data.data.items.length);
      setSearchKey("");
      setCurrentFilter(filterPull);
      setCurrentSorter(sorterPull);
    } else setSmsg(response.data.msg);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    pullData(sc.Snumber.numToPullMail, [], []);
  }, []);
```

I'm wondering is this a designed mechanism in React Native? or there are other ways to reduce render-times?

Above example is simple in my project though - I have some complex components in which have more than 20 setState in-used, also with ~10 functions in each component. If setState causes re-render 20+ times plus re-creation of functions, the resource waste is probably considerable...

I don't want to use Redux, useCallback and would like know 1) is this normal in React Native world? (render 20 times for any component); 2) is there smarter way to avoid resource waste in virtual DOM comparision? (in example above, I didn't see any reason have to render component 5 times for codes written in sequence

```
  setShowList(response.data.data.items);
  setNumOfDataPulled(response.data.data.items.length);
  setSearchKey("");
  setCurrentFilter(filterPull);
  setCurrentSorter(sorterPull);
```

)

Thanks!

Comment: If you change the state, React _should_ rerender. That's the point of state: it reflects a state of your component and any change implies a difference in how it should be presented to the user. But, if you have a bunch of values that always update "together", then don't use separate state variables for each of them, use a single object on which you update three, four, seven, etc. properties in a single setState call.

Comment: the reason I use separate state is they might be updated separately (later in UI). If I use single object, that means there would be un-necessary update as waste as well...

Comment: No there wouldn't? Whether you update all properties or only a single one, you call setState to signal to React that you updated the component's state and that it should update how the component is rendered. And note that it's not "either 1 giant object, or 20 separate variables". Bundle the things that you know always update together, and don't bundle the ones that don't. Just know that when you update the state, React _should_ rerender. That's essentialy why you're using React in the first place here: to model your UI using stateful components.

Comment: thanks! we have one render but probably more updates, for example: <com1 para1={object.a} /> <com2 para2={object.b} /> if I setState for object per scenario com1, during the re-rendering, com2 would be updated due to {object} change though scenario com2 is irrelevant? am I right?

Comment: Why would it get updated? React render passes only update things linked to data that changed. If you update `object.a` then com1 will be rerendered, and if `object.b` didn't change, then `com2` stays the way it was. Do not confuse "the render function gets called" with "and the UI got updated". That is not how React works. The render function gets called, it computes a new virtual DOM, and based on it then only updates the parts of your UI that actually changed compared to the previous vdom.

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I want to clarify: if I setState for object, all DOM elements with {object} would be updated, no matter object.a or object.b? (during virtual DOM update)

Comment: But that's not what you're showing. You said `<com1 para1={object.a} />`, which _does not use `object`_, it uses a property _from_ `object`. So if you update your state with a new `a` but keep the previous `b`, then `<com1>` will update because its `para` property changed, and `<com2>` won't, because its `para` property did _not_ change.

Comment: in this case, should we create a virtual object, including all states used in component, that would help avoid unnecessary re-renders?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "unnecessary render". That's what I've been trying to explain in the past few comments. React _should_ call render, what _actual performance problem_ are you trying to solve here? Because if you just think you should reduce the number of render calls: you shouldn't. This is literally the thing that React was designed around, it is doing exactly what it was designed to do. The only thing you should answer is "are you updating your state sensibly" and in this case it feels like you probably aren't, and an object might make more sense.

Comment: So barring updates to your post to [include all the details](/help/how-to-ask) that keep you asking more and more questions, let's cut this off here: there are _loads_ of excellent React tutorials including the ones on the React site, which I strongly advise giving a (re)read for inspiration, and if you're not experiencing actual performance problems, don't try to optimize React's render mechanism.

Comment: thanks, this is a great point ...if you're not experiencing actual performance problems, don't try to optimize React's render mechanism...

Answer (score 0):

If you use react 18 (which was enabled by default in React Native 0.69), setting multiple states like this will do just one render:

```
setToSpin(false);

if (response.data.suc) {
  setShowList(response.data.data.items);
  setNumOfDataPulled(response.data.data.items.length);
  setSearchKey("");
  setCurrentFilter(filterPull);
  setCurrentSorter(sorterPull);
} else setSmsg(response.data.msg);
```

Prior to react 17, react could *usually* batch them together, but not always. One of those cases which did not work was the one you have in your example: in an async function after an await. For this case, each of the calls to set state would cause its own render, not a single batched one.

In react 17 you can force these to be batched by the use of `unstable_batchedUpdates`:

```
import { unstable_batchedUpdates } from 'react-native' // or in web, from 'react-dom'

// ...

unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
  setToSpin(false);

  if (response.data.suc) {
    setShowList(response.data.data.items);
    setNumOfDataPulled(response.data.data.items.length);
    setSearchKey("");
    setCurrentFilter(filterPull);
    setCurrentSorter(sorterPull);
  } else setSmsg(response.data.msg);
});
```

Comment: this is also what I want...but my react version is 18.1.0 (react-native 0.70.5), from my test seems not by batch

Comment: probably not ready in React Native https://medium.com/achieving-100ms/part-1-automatic-batching-w-react-native-fabric-react-18-438ad1282896

Comment: I created a new app folder with React 18.2/React Native 0.71 and copy all codes under that new architecture but the problem is still there (no auto-batching)...do you know the reason? https://reactnative.dev/docs/react-18-and-react-native#react-18-and-the-react-native-new-architecture

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're observing is a common characteristic of React and React Native, known as "reconciliation". When a component's state changes, React checks to see if any of the component's child elements need to be re-rendered. If any of the child elements need to be updated, then the entire component is re-rendered.

In the example you provided, the component is re-rendered 7 times because there are 7 state updates triggered by the set functions inside the pullData function. This is a normal behavior in React and React Native, and it is how the framework ensures that the UI is always up-to-date with the application's state.

Here's a way you could resolve this by React.Memo

```
import React, { memo, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = memo(() => {
const [showList, setShowList] = useState([]);
const [numOfDataPulled, setNumOfDataPulled] = useState(0);
const [searchKey, setSearchKey] = useState("");
const [currentFilter, setCurrentFilter] = useState([]);
const [currentSorter, setCurrentSorter] = useState([]);
const [toSpin, setToSpin] = useState(false);

const pullData = async (numToPull, filterPull, sorterPull) => {
    setToSpin(true);
    const response = await AxiosPost(
        sc.Slink.getMailInbox,
        {
            page: 1,
            pageSize: numToPull,
            filterOption: [
                ...filterPull,
                {
                    key: "isUnread",
                    value: true,
                },
            ],
            sortOption: sorterPull,
        },
        { Authorization: ctxt.authInfo.tokenSF },
        { studio: ctxt.roomInfo.currentLoginRoom }
    );

    setToSpin(false);

    if (response.data.suc) {
        setShowList(response.data.data.items);
        setNumOfDataPulled(response.data.data.items.length);
        setSearchKey("");
        setCurrentFilter(filterPull);
        setCurrentSorter(sorterPull);
    } else setSmsg(response.data.msg);
};

useEffect(() => {
    pullData(sc.Snumber.numToPullMail, [], []);
}, []);

return (
    <div>
        // render your component here
    </div>
);
});

export default MyComponent;
```